# Handle Click Event in a Stateless component and inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using ReactJs and I have two stateless components:

The parent component receive a list of projects

```
{currentProjectData.map((project) => (
    <ProjectItem
      key={project.projectid}
      id={project.projectid}
      project={project}
    />
  ))}
```

and the child component receive the key

```
 return (
    <Card key={id} elevation={5} className={classes.root}>
      <Box
        borderLeft={componentItem.borderLeftValue}
        borderColor={componentItem.borderColorValue}
        onMouseOver={handleChangeOnMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleChangeOnMouseLeave}
      ></Card>)
```

I am having trouble trying to handle click event when someone clicks in the card i need the key

```
 const handleClick = (key) => {
   console.log(key);
  };
```

I put click event inside Card

```
<Card
  key={id}
  elevation={5}
  className={classes.root}
  onClick={handleClick(id)}
>
```

but the click event trigger when I move the cursor inside the card

[image]

Where should I handle the click event (Parent Component or Child Component) and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be on Card, what you pass to handleClick depends upon how you use props in child component, you can pass key or id. Syntax can be props.key or props.id as well if you are not destructuring props.

```
return (
    <Card key={id} elevation={5} className={classes.root} onClick={()=>handleClick(id)}>
      <Box
        borderLeft={componentItem.borderLeftValue}
        borderColor={componentItem.borderColorValue}
        onMouseOver={handleChangeOnMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleChangeOnMouseLeave}
      ></Card>)
```

Comment: I tried, but the click event trigger when I move the cursor inside the card is not when I click in the card I don't know why

Comment: Try passing callback function {()=>handle Click(id)}

Comment: HandleClick needs to be in child unless you are passing it as prop from parent

Comment: Yes , it works!! passing callback function {()=>handle Click(id)} @SM1105922